# Data view schema in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views, schema-builder

How all data views are connected to each other in salesforce marketing cloud?

Comment: It would be better if you share a first draft of data views data model.

Answer (score 2):

The most common case would be to leverage joins on "jobid" or "SubscriberKey".

For instance (I am using _job and _open data views)

```
SELECT 
j.[JobID]
,j.[JobType]
,o.[EventDate]
FROM _job as j

JOIN _open as o
ON j.[JobID] = o.[JobID]
```

1. What is your use case?
2. Which data views hold the data you're interested in?
3. Do they "share" any fields?
4. Analyse the schema and write your SQL.

Comment: It is better to join these views on subscriberid vs subscriberkey